# Can this be formalized in terms of mixed-integer linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to solve a problem where there are a group of objects that need to move between various points at specific times.

I have been able to formalize most of the constraints in terms of linear programming, i.e.:

```
object1FirstDepartureTime > X
object1FirstArrivalTime < Y
object1FirstArrivalTime - object1FirstDepartureTime > Z
object1SecondDepartureTime - object1FirstArrivalTime > A
```

And so forth and so on for all the objects and all of their arrivals/departures.  The objective function will be to spend either the least or most possible time in transit.

The problem I'm having is with one additional constraint: certain objects need to be accompanied for the duration of their trip by other objects.  For example, object1 could be accompanied by object2, object3, or object4.  These objects themselves have certain arrival or departure constraints.  I'd like to make my (perhaps mixed-integer) linear program take care of the picking of the accompanying object.  But while trying to formalize this, I can't figure out a way to keep it linear.  I have thought of mixed-integer constraints like

```
object2GoWIthObject1 + object3GoWithObject1 + object4GoWithObject1 < 2
object2GoWIthObject1, object3GoWithObject1, object4GoWithObject1 are all less than 2
object2GoWIthObject1, object3GoWithObject1, object4GoWithObject1 are all integers
```

But I can't figure out how to express constraints like "If object 2 accompanies object 1, it will depart at time X with object 1 and arrive at time Y."  This seems non-linear, as I'd be multiplying the boolean variable (if object 2 accompanies object 1) by the time of travel.

Of course, I could just create different linear problems for every "if...then..." statement, but with 60ish accompanied paths and 10ish accompanying objects, this'd lead to 10^60 linear programs to solve, which is not good.

If anyone has any intuition as to how to formalize this linear programming problem so that the decisions of "will X accompany Y?" can be expressed in the problem itself, I'd be much obliged!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can modify the formulation to handle your constraints. There are many standard tricks involving the "Big-M" and new 0-1 to accomplish this. (Han's response rightly suggests this.)

In order to accommodate your specific non-linear constraints, you would introduce new 0-1 variables (like your "GoWith" variables) and then add extra *linear* constraints in your formulation.

Let's take your stated requirement: **If object 2 accompanies object 1, it will depart at time X with object 1 and arrive at time Y**

```
Start1 >= X 
Arrive1 <= Y
```

are constraints that you already have for Object 1.

Let's introduce the binary variable **Z12** which is 1 if Object2 travels with Object1, Z12 = 0 otherwise.

So,

```
If Z12 = 1, then Start2 > X
If Z12 = 1 then Arrive2 < Y
```

We can rewrite this as:

```
Start2 - X >= 0 if Z12 =1
Start2 - X >= -M if Z12 =0, where M is a large number.
```

Combine them into one linear constraint:

```
Start2 - X >= M(Z12-1)
```

This constraint is binding when Z12 is 1, and is trivially satisfied otherwise.

Likewise, for the arrival of Object2 to match the arrival of Object1, you would write:

```
Arrive2 < Y if Z12=1
Arrive2 < M if Z12=0
```

Which becomes

```
Arrive2 < Y + M(1-Z12), a linear constraint.
```

By similarly introducing binary variables Z13, Z14 etc. you can take care of all your constraints in just one linear formulation.

More "tricks" to use in IP formulation can be found at:
http://agecon2.tamu.edu/people/faculty/mccarl-bruce/mccspr/new15.pdf

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the big-M method like this:

```
object1FirstDepartureTime - object2FirstDepartureTime > -M * object2GoWIthObject1
object1FirstDepartureTime - object2FirstDepartureTime < M * object2GoWIthObject1
```

M is a sufficiently large constant.  The problem with the big-M approach is that it leads to a poor LP relaxation.